# require n out of m keys/users to authenticate an ssh session?

Tags: ssh, authentication

I'm looking for an option - eventually to extend standard ssh - in such a way that I need (at least) two people/keys out of m possible to authenticate a session instead of one out of m known once...

anyone seen this or know how to do?

I know there is key + password (which is kind of this direction) but not exactly what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 1):

If you set up `AuthenticationMethods publickey,publickey` in your `sshd_config`, the authentication will succeed only if the authentication using two different keys was successful.

Comment: I'll give it a try - and see how this works - also on the connecting client side - sounds good so far!

Answer (score 1):

I think SSH does not do this right away.

You may take a look at [privacyIDEA](https://privacyidea.org) which is a multifactor authentication system. It was originally designed to do one time passwords but does a lot more now.

It also support a two-man-rule authentication token, which you can use to do exactly, what you recommended. You can define, that e.g. the user "root" can login, if "n" persons of group1, "m" persons of group2, "x" persons of group3... authenticate togeather.

Read more about the so called "4 eyes token" http://privacyidea.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/tokens/4eyes.html

Disclaimer: I am the lead developer of privacyIDEA.

Comment: I'll have a look into this - sounds good too!